# SQL. Unique and Primary Key

Tags: mysql, primary-key, unique-key

My requirement is having a table of products which cannot have similar vendor, product and version at the same time.

But, I also want this table to be referenced on another table by its primary key, as for the distinct vendor, product version I use `unique`.

```
create table Products
    (
    vendor varchar(100),
    product varchar(100),
    version varchar(30),
    unique (vendor, product, version, cve)        
);
```

But this way I cannot reference it by its `product_id`, as I want to in another table:

```
create table Product_cve(

    product_id int,
    cve varchar(14),
    foreign key (product_id) references Products(product_id),
    foreign key (cve) references VulnerabilitiesCVE(cve)
);
```

, another thing I can do is that

```
   create table Products
    (
    product_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vendor varchar(100),
    product varchar(100),
    version varchar(30),
    primary key (product_id)

    );
```

This way, I am going to end up having duplicated products...

Comment: You should ideally maintain just the `product_id` and `product_name` in the `Products` table and create another mapping table which has `product` and `vendor`, say `product_vendor`. Then you can use the `product_vendor_id` (PK of `product_vendor` table) as foreign key in `Product_cve` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple:

```
create table Products
    (
    product_id int AUTO_INCREMENT
    vendor varchar(100),
    product varchar(100),
    version varchar(30),
    UNIQUE(vendor, product, version, cve),
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)        
);
```